# using variable in regex with mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, regex

i need to search a specific word in database, my query is like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE question REGEXP '\\bis\\b';
```

it works good...
but in my python script i use this and nothing happens!

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                            password='----',
                            host='127.0.0.1',
                            database='test',
                            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

t = input()

query = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE question REGEXP '\\b%s\\b';" % t

cursor.execute(query)
cnx.commit()

for q,one,two,three,four in cursor:
    print(q+'\n',one+'\n',two+'\n',three+'\n',four)

cnx.close()
```

how can i use a variable in this case!?
Thanks

Comment: You're using `LIKE` in your script and `REGEXP` in your working example. Should you be using a regex instead of like?

Comment: @IainShelvington Sorry I wrote it wrong. The problem is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in Python, a doube-quoted string literal uses the backslash *also* as escape character, just like MySQL.

Either escape both backslashes in each pair:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE question REGEXP '\\\\b%s\\\\b';", (t,))
```

...or use the `r` prefix to have a *raw string* where backslashes are not interpreted as escape characters (for Python):

```
c.execute(r"SELECT * FROM test WHERE question REGEXP '\\b%s\\b';", (t,))
```

Comment: `r` prefix working

Answer (score 0):

You should be using REGEXP in your query instead of LIKE (the way you used in the console). You can try something like this:

```
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE question REGEXP '\\b%s\\b';", (t,))
```

Assuming t is your input

Comment: hey! yes i wrote LIKE wrong. i tried this and still nothing show...idk why!!!

Comment: Can you give an example string which you need to match?